# Windows application resolution on surface pro 3

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, winjs, screen-resolution

I have a probleme with surface pro application. I make an application with visual studio 2015, a winjs application. My html files are designed to be 2160*1440, in simulator i have chose 2160 * 1440 and every things are ok. but when i debug  application on surface with computer local(for debug), the resoltuion is too big.i don't understand why.
thank for your help

Comment: How have you designed your application to fit that resolution? Please provide code if available. What do you mean with "resolution too big" and which resolution are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you are lacking more information,
I guess you have DPI scaling on (since its default enabled on surface devices) the DPI scaling might get you into those troubles.
Try disable DPI scaling.

Start -> Settings -> System -> Display (in Windows 10)

move the scaling bar to 100%.

[image: DPI Scaling Dialog]

Important! restart your computer to apply the changes and avoid problems.

Now try again your program. It should scale as intended. :)